# Android ScrollView's ContentViewGroup's Child not respecting match_parent

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a layout which look like the following:

`ScrollView(match_parent, match_parent)
   - RelativeLayout(match_parent, 1000dp)
      - ImageView(match_parent, match_parent)`

The problem is that ImageView's height is not matching parent when it is being layout.
Anyone know why this is happening and any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ScrollView will automatically force its child to wrap its content, no matter whether you tell it to FILL_PARENT or MATCH_PARENT or specify any other size... Thats why it is not working...

Comment: I change the RelativeLayout height to wrap_content and ImageView to 1000dp. and its works. No ideas why android scroll view and view group have this kind of strange behaviour.

Comment: Ya, but have not idea why child's match_parent is not working but the other around with wrap_content's parent is working. strange android.

Comment: Hey the answer has been updated Hope it will be useful to others as well...